# Burning songs to a virtual CD

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, music, cd-burning

I have a playlist of 180 songs that I downloaded from the internet. I imported it into iTunes, but all the data for the songs was put into their name. for example: `001 - artist - song title` was put into the ‘song name’ section and the rest of the data fields were left blank. I tried getting track names from gracenote or whatever iTunes uses, but it said that I need to import the songs through iTunes in order to do that. 
So basically, what I want is a way that I can burn the 180 songs (1.5gb) onto a virtual CD and then have iTunes import from the CD. 
I have tried using [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html)’s burn to .dmg function but it has a 99 song limit for burning CD’s. I have also tried using [Virtual CD-RW](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33355/virtual-cd-rw) but Finder wouldn't let me burn the files to the virtual CD it had created because there was ‘not enough space on the disk’ 

Is there an app that can create a virtual CD (CD-R/CD-RW) that I can burn 1.5gb of music to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No music formatted CD can hold 1.5 GB. I suspect most virtual CD software will deliberately limit the maximum contents size to 800 MB to mimic real CD limits.

Have you considered using a script to extract the information from the filename and set the results as metadata?

[Manage MP3 ID3 tag information from the command line](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) discusses a suitable command line tool available.

iTunes supports AppleScript and the [Doug Scripts](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030805003033280) web site appears to have a good selection of example scripts.

Comment: Thnaks. Doug Scripts was awesome and did the job!